# Black screen between two activity using animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I am using Apis 's deme for slide-in and slide-out between two activity. But when I jump from one activity to another a black screen is appearing.

Slide-Left-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

Slide-Right-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

To Jump from one activity to another:-

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondView.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right);
```

});

Why is this black screen is appearing between two activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first xml should be like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

fromXDelta is the horizontal translation applied at the beginning of the animation. Setting it to "100%p" makes the first activity shift just right out of the screen at the inception of the animation, hence the blank screen.

The call to the function `overridePendingTransition(int, int)` should be like this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left);
```

The first argument determines the transition animation used by the **second** activity. Also the two animations can be more properly named as slide_out_to_right and slide_in_from_left, since in fact they all slide to the right.

Comment: Works fine for me..thaanks...Couldnt vote your answer coz of lower reputation....My other code should side the animation from right side.the below code is again leaving blank screen. <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

Comment: @topduo: am working with slideup and slidedown animations.. still shows black screen between transition